# Is it possible to put a data table in the sidebar in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I would like my side bar to have a reactive table in it similar to the picture shown. Is this possible? Thank you.

[image: Image of a data table in the side of a shinydashboard]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tableOutput` inside `dashboardSidebar`; you can add the table as you desire.

Please see an example below:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

if(interactive()){
  shinyApp(
    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "My Dashboard"),
      dashboardSidebar(width = "300px",
                       br(),
                       br(),
                       tableOutput("data1")),
      dashboardBody()
    ),

    server = function(input, output, session){
      output$data1 <- renderTable({
        head(mtcars[,1:4])
      })
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: This worked, Thank you!